# Wolfram Language, RandomChoice recursion

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

```
a = RandomChoice[{a,2}]&
a[]
```

There are other ways to achieve this example, but I wish to do more complicated things similar to this using this method.

Can I get this to continue until there are no `a`s left to resolve, without producing a stack overflow by trying to resolve `{a,2}` before making the choice? Instead making the choice and resolving only the symbol chosen.

Comment: what do you mean by no a's left to resolve? this looks like it should keep,recusing until it randomly chooses 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to have `RandomChoice` evaluate a function only when selected:

```
 g := (Print["evaluate g"]; 42);
 f = ( If[TrueQ[#], g, #] &@RandomChoice[{True, 1, 2, 3, 4}]) &
 Table[f[], {10}]
```

this prints  "evaluate g" just when randomly selected and outputs eg.

```
 (* {2, 42, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 42, 2, 4} *)
```

This is another way, maybe a bit cleaner:

```
 f = Unevaluated[{g, 1, 2, 3, 4}][[RandomInteger[{1, 5}]]] &
```

this works fine recursively:

```
 a = Unevaluated[{a[], 2}][[RandomInteger[{1, 2}]]] &
```

Though as i said in comment it simply returns 2 every time since it recurses until 2 is chosen.

```
 a[] (* 2 *)
```

I do not understand the entirety of the question and my guess is there is a better way to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your request seems slightly contradictory: when the random choice selects `a` you want it to recurse, but if it chooses a number you still want to continue until there are no `a`'s left.

The following code does this, but the recursion is technically unnecessary.  Perhaps in your application it will be applicable.

The first part shows how you can recurse selections of `a` by using `Hold` :-

```
Clear[a]

list = {1, 2, a, 1, a, 3, a, 1, 4, 5};

heldlist = Hold /@ list;

a := Module[{z}, z = RandomChoice[heldlist]; 
  Print["for information, choice was ", z];
  If[MatchQ[z, Hold[_Symbol]],
   heldlist = DeleteCases[heldlist, z, 1, 1];
   If[MemberQ[heldlist, Hold[_Symbol]], ReleaseHold[z]]]] 

a
```

On this occasion, calling `a` recurses once, then picks a 4 and stops, as expected.

> for information, choice was Hold[a]
>
> for information, choice was Hold[4]

To make the process continue until there are no `a`'s `While` can be used.  There is recursion going on here too but `While` keeps the process going when a number is picked.

```
While[MemberQ[heldlist, Hold[_Symbol]], a]
```

> for information, choice was Hold[a]
>
> for information, choice was Hold[1]
>
> for information, choice was Hold[a]

These are the remaining items in the list :-

```
ReleaseHold /@ heldlist
```

> {1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5}